# NodeJS sample app failing to startup, unable to find 'config'?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, npm

I'm learning node and am trying to run a sample app I've pulled from git:

https://github.com/madhums/node-express-mongoose-demo

After following all the instructions, when I run

```
npm start
```

I get an error that says

```
> nodejs-express-mongoose-demo@4.0.0 start /Users/adam419/Desktop/Programming/JSPractice/node-express-mongoose-demo
> NODE_PATH=./config:./app/controllers NODE_ENV=development ./node_modules/.bin/nodemon server.js

20 Dec 16:45:19 - [nodemon] v1.2.1
20 Dec 16:45:19 - [nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
20 Dec 16:45:19 - [nodemon] watching: *.*
20 Dec 16:45:19 - [nodemon] starting `node --harmony server.js`
WARNING: No configurations found in configuration directory:
WARNING: /Users/adam419/Desktop/Programming/JSPractice/node-express-mongoose-demo/config
WARNING: See https://www.npmjs.org/package/config for more information.

module.js:340
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module 'undefined/config/imager.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/adam419/Desktop/Programming/JSPractice/node-express-mongoose-demo/app/models/article.js:10:20)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
20 Dec 16:45:20 - [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

This occcurs after making sure I have mongodb installed and running, making sure I've installed all dependencies including 'config'. In fact in node shell when I run

```
require('config')
```

the result is undefined.

Why is this application failing to start?

Answer (score 5):

I saw that this can happen when the `NODE_CONFIG_DIR` environment variable is not set. It tells node-config where to find the config files. By default reads configuration files in the ./config directory for the running process, typically the application root.

The [node-config docs](https://github.com/lorenwest/node-config/wiki/Configuration-Files#config-directory) suggest setting this env variable either in the CLI or in your config file like so:

```
process.env["NODE_CONFIG_DIR"] = __dirname;
```

`__dirname` is OK if the config file is in the same folder as where your default.EXT and other configuration files are, but you might need to change it to the actual path where those files are.

otherwise, we end up with: `"WARNING: No configurations found in configuration directory:<PROJECT_ROOT>/config/config"` and, subsequently, an error like: `'Configuration property "some-config-key" is not defined'`

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar error.

**The problem:** I created the `config` folder in a sub folder within the root directory.

**The solution:** Moved the `config` folder to the root directory.

Another possible cause of the error could be due to the absence of the configuration files (e.g. `config/default.json`, `config/production.json`, etc.) in the config folder.

Comment: This solved my problem thank you. I was following a tutorial but did not notice the level of the directory.

Answer (score 2):

Deleting the config folder that was in my node_modules folder fixed the problem.

Comment: Yes, that solved the problem for me also. But can you please explain why having this config folder messes things up? and how it was created?

Comment: you deleted the config module... you dosnt suppose to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Thats because config must be loaded relatively. The `require('config')` statement tries to find a module named config in your node_modules directory, where as config here is in the config directory of your root folder. Try changing `require('config')` to `require('../../config')`. That should solve your problem.

Comment: There actually is a folder named config inside the node_modules directory, also the require('../../config') didn't work.

Comment: @AdamBronfin what is being required is the module, not the folder containing the configurations. This module will, by default, look into the root directory and find the config folder there. Thus, `require('config')` is correct.

Answer (score 0):

In my case forgot to export the config object in the config file (default.js)

module.exports = config